# How to extract uuid inserted into a row as a primary key via a trigger

Tags: mysql, primary-key, replication, uuid

Consider the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `information` (
    `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
    `data` text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

with the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `information_uuid_ins_trg` 
BEFORE INSERT ON information 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.id = UUID();
END;
```

What I'd like to be able to do, is to know the id that was used with the previous insert statement.

INSERT INTO information ( data ) VALUES ('[some data]')

Given a replicated master-master environment where the [some data] is not guaranteed to be unique. Obviously the [last_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) can't be used since the field is not an auto_increment field. Adding an update of a temp table with LAST_INSERT_ID(UUID(  )) won't work since LAST_INSERT_ID(expr) expects an integer value as expr. In OracleRDBMS I would approach this with:

```
INSERT INTO information 
(data) values ('[some data]') 
RETURNING id INTO var_id
```

or with Microsoft SQL Server / Postgres I would use:

```
INSERT INTO information 
(data) values ('[some data]') 
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
```

This would all be called from a PHP frontend running on a collection of webservers.

Any thoughts as to how to return the uuid pk in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MySQL doesn't seem to have any built in functionality to help you out, I sadly can't think of anything better than this "hack";

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `information_uuid_retrieve` 
AFTER INSERT ON information 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  SET @INSERT_ID=NEW.id; 
END;//

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO information (data) VALUES ('olle');

SELECT @INSERT_ID;
+--------------------------------------+
| @INSERT_ID                           |
+--------------------------------------+
| f42f4044-58d0-11e1-8f90-93738648d450 |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Why the two step process? Why not SET @INSERT_ID = NEW.ID ?

Comment: @MichaelMacDonald Good point, I got an error earlier about no statement being defined, but when I try now again it seems to work just fine. Updating the answer with the simpler version.

Comment: I've been testing this out in our environment and it will work for our needs. Thanks for the suggestion.